# How do I enforce users to fill a determined custom field using WyPiekacz?

Tags: plugins, custom-field

I have a Wordpress + Buddypress site.

I've created two custom fields which **must** be filled in each post. Also, I have a form in a custom metabox to show them.

I'm using [WyPiekacz plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wypiekacz/) to check for minimun words, tags, and categories. So it would be nice if I can tweak it a litle to check if these custom fields were filled or not, and set the post status to draft if the custom fields were empty.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I have no experience with this plugin. But when I look at the source, I think something like this should do it:

```
add_filter( 'wypiekacz_check_post', 'wpse_78395check' );

function wpse_78395check( $errors )
{
    if ( empty ( $_POST['custom_field_name'] ) )
        $errors[] = array (
            'unique_error_key',
            __( 'Custom error message', 'your_textdomain' )
        );

    return $errors;
}
```

Replace all strings in this example with something useful. :)

Comment: :D
I just did a litle change to your answer, and now it works: 

add_filter( 'wypiekacz_check_post', 'creepy_fuentecheck' );

function creepy_fuentecheck( $errors )
{
    global $post;
    $mustFill = '';
    $mustFill = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_field_name', true);
    if ( empty ( $mustFill ) )
        $errors[] = array (
            'fuente_vacia',
            __( 'Por favor, agrega la fuente', 'wypiekacz' )
        );


    return $errors;
}


Thanks!